# Minimum vertex cover and odd cycles

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, optimization, linear-programming

Suppose we have a graph $G$. Consider the minimum vertex cover problem of $G$ formulated as a linear programming problem, that is for each vertex $v_{i}$ we have the variable $x_{i}$, for each edge $v_{i}v_{j}$ we have the constraint $x_{i}+x_{j}\geq 1$, for each variable we have $0\leq x_{i}\leq 1$ and we have the objective function $\min \sum\limits_{1}^{n}{x_{i}}$. We say such a linear programming problem *LP*. Note that it is NOT an integer linear programming problem.

We find a [half integral optimal solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) of *LP* that we say $S_{hi}$. For each variable $x_{i}$ that takes value *0* in $S_{hi}$, we add the constraint $x_{i}=0$ to *LP*.

For each odd cycle of $G$, add to *LP* the constraint $x_{a}+x_{b}+x_{c}+...+x_{i}\geq \frac{1}{2}(k+1)$ where $x_{a},x_{b},x_{c},...,x_{i}$ are the vertices of the cycle and $k$ is the number of vertices of the cycle. We find a new optimal solution of *LP* that we say $S$.

If $x_{i}$ is a variable that takes value $0.5$ in $S_{hi}$ and value $\gt 0.5$ in $S$, can we say that there is at least a minimum vertex cover of $G$ that contains the vertex associated to $x_{i}$?

**The idea behind the question**: in an odd cycle $c$ with $k$ vertices, the number of vertices needed to cover the cycle is $\frac{1}{2}(k+1)$, therefore for each odd cycle we add to *LP* the constraint $x_{a}+x_{b}+x_{c}+...+x_{i}\geq \frac{1}{2}(k+1)$. If in $S_{hi}$ the sum of the variables of $c$ is $\frac{k}{2}$ (that is all the variables of $c$ take value $\frac{1}{2}$), then in $S$ at least a variable $x_{i}$ of $c$ takes vale $\gt \frac{1}{2}$ and the vertex associated to $x_{i}$ belongs to at least a minimum vertex cover of the given graph.

Comment: If you want to attract attention to your question, [start a bounty](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/q/3989/2415.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.